# Displaying a month according to the Date

Tags: php, arrays

I have been writing code to show a month, according to the day of the current month.

**For example:**

If we are between the 1st and the 10th of the actual month, I want to display the actual month.
If we are after the 10th of the actual month, I want to display the next month.

*So, if we are the **March, 1st**, I want **'March'** to display.*

*But if we were the **March, 22,** I want **'April'** to display.*

I wanted the months displaying in Spanish. I've already done this by the following code.

**Code:**

```
function date_es($format = 'F', $time = null){ 
    if(empty($time)) $time = time(); 

    $date = date($format, $time); 

    $mois_en = array("January","February","March","April","May","June","July","August","September","October","November","December"); 
    $mois_es = array("Enero","Febrero","Marzo","Abril","Mayo","Junio","Julio","Agosto","Septiembre","Octubre","Noviembre","Diciembre"); 

    $date = str_replace($mois_en, $mois_es, $date); 

    return $date; 
}
```

**However, I do not know how to include the conditional statements to this code ?**

Cheers for any help.

Comment: `if (date('d') > 10) {}`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to get day of the month - use `j` formating option.

In my opinion you function should look like:

```
function date_es($format = 'F', $time = null){
    if(empty($time)) $time = time();

    // get day num
    $day_num = date('j', $time);

    // get month num
    $month_num = date('n',  $time);
    if ($day_num > 10) {
        // add 1 if day is more then 10
        $month_num += 1;
        // if your month is December, 
        // then `$month_num` is 13
        // but you don't need this)
        $month_num %= 12;
    }

    $mois_es = array("Enero","Febrero","Marzo","Abril","Mayo","Junio","Julio","Agosto","Septiembre","Octubre","Noviembre","Diciembre");

    // return month name
    //I added `- 1` because keys in `$mois_es` start with zero
    return $mois_es[$month_num == 0? 11 : $month_num - 1];
}
```